# How to mock method with FilterExpression input parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamics-crm-2011, moq

I’m trying to mock method using Moq that takes FilterExpression as an input parameter and I have no luck so far. When I run it is always returns null. If I pass `NULL` instead of FilterExpression it works.

Here is my code:

Repository

```
public interface ITestRepository
{
string Test(int id, FilterExpression fe);
}

public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
        public stringTest(int id, FilterExpression fe)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Unit Test

```
var testMock = new Mock<ITestRepository>();
var fe = new FilterExpression();
var result = “Hello World”;
var  id = 1;

//DOESN’T WORK
testMock.Setup(r => r.Test(id, filterExpression)).Returns(result);

//WORKS
testMock.Setup(r => r.Test(id, null)).Returns(result);

//Test
[TestMethod]
public void test()
{
    var fe = new FilterExpression();
    var id = 1;        
    _testRepository.Test(id, fe);
    _testRepository.Test(id, null);       
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the filterexpression class fullname with namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments don't match. You use different *FilterExpression*s. Have you tried to put any *FilterExpression*?

```
testMock.Setup(r => r.Test(id, It.IsAny<FilterExpression>())).Returns(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should contain the original object; in your code sample it does not:

```
testMock.Setup(r => r.Test(id, filterExpression)).Returns(result);
```

to

```
testMock.Setup(r => r.Test(id, fe)).Returns(result);
```

According to your test above.  Also, where is your setup of the test objects defined? these should also be defined within the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to unit test Dynamics CRM code, then did you try [FakeXrmEasy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy)?

It's an open source project I have been working on since 2014 which automatically mocks IOrganizationService calls for you, including your FilterExpressions, but also any QueryExpression (with joins, filters, nested linked entities, order by), QueryByAttribute, FetchXml, the main basic CRUD and also other messages like Associate, Disassociate, ExecuteMultiple, WhoAmIRequests, and so on and so on...

It's really robust, it has more 800+ unit tests to test the testing framework itself (yeah, how meta is that? ) and the feedback, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317808/crm-2016-fakexrmeasy-nn-relationships) one, is excellent! :)

It definetely helps me on a daily basis and though of open sourcing it to help other CRM developers, and also so that other developers from the community could also contribute with their own improvements and new features (please do so).

It is available as a NuGet package too which makes it really easy to get started with. Please have a look at the documentation page [here](http://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview).

I actually started working on another repository to do the same thing for Web API calls from Javascript.

Stay tunned & happy testing!